# flex XMLSocket over ssl

Tags: apache-flex, ssl, xmlsocket

i am writing a flash app that receives its data over a XMLSocket. On the testmachine that worked really fine, but now the data will be ssl secured. Is there any XMLSSLSocket or something similar available? If not XMLSocket a normal SSLSocket would be a great help as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use binary sockets and as3crypto: http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/

Answer (score 0):

The opensource Forge project that does SSL/TLS in JavaScript and raw sockets via Flash might help:

http://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/blob/master/README